# When to use lock and unnamed mutex in .NET?

Tags: .net, multithreading, locking, mutex

NET threading experts,

I know that lock works across threads within a process and 'named mutex' works across processes. However 'unnamed mutex' also seems to be working across threads (similar to lock). Now can someone throw the light on real world uses of unnamed lock which lock can't handle?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: C# locks are implemented on top of mutex and both serve same purpose. However mutex are low level and managed answer to OS mutex.

Comment: There's just more than one way to implement thread synchronization in .NET.  The *lock* keyword is an easy abstraction for the Monitor class and very often usable as-is.  And you have Mutex, Semaphore/Slim, AutoResetEvent, ManualResetEvent/Slim, CountDownEvent, ReaderWriterLock/Slim classes at your disposal.  Kinda important to know what they can do to know when to use them, it is already very well covered in the MSDN documentation and many web pages.

Answer (score 2):

[Mutexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx) can be passed as a parameter to a function, locks can't. Mutexes are also `MarshalByRefObject` so then can be passed between AppDomains.

There are sometimes situations where you would like to lock across AppDomains within a program, for that you can use a unnamed mutex.

`lock` is built on top of low level mutexes with some logic applied to them, and `Mutex` is just a direct managed wrapper of those low level mutexes. Don't think of it as a either/or situation, instead think of it more like the relationship of [`TcpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) vs [`WebClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx), you can use `TcpClient` to do all of the things `WebClient` does but it is easier to use the higher layer abstraction to do your work.

Comment: Thnx Scott for your answer. So you mean mutex is more abstract than lock?

Comment: I would call a `lock` "more abstract" because it is not directly manipulating OS mutexes like `Mutex` does.